# How can I hide INPUT value?JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

https://jsfiddle.net/huat81z4/

CODE HTML:

```
<input class="search" value="Search" type="text" size="18" name="s" id="s">
```

CODE JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('input .search).click(function(){
             $(".this").attr("value", "");
      });
});
```

I want to disappear the word "Search" when the user clicks on the form.
What is wrong with my code?

Is there any function that makes it better?

Comment: Your string isn’t closed.

Comment: $(".this") ? $('input .search') For this case use placeholder attribute

Answer (score 3):

use placeholder attribute

```
<input class="search" placeholder="Search" type="text" size="18" name="s" id="s">
```

Comment: excelent tip, JS is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

Just use placeholder attribute instead of value.

```
<input class="search" placeholder="Search" type="text" size="18" name="s" id="s">
```

Or if you want to do it in a script do it like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.search').click(function(){
             $(this).attr("value", "");
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
<input class="search" placeholder="Search" type="text" size="18" name="s" id="s">
```

This will put a placeholder text inside your text input, and when someone tries to enter anything, it will be gone.

But if you want to stick to js, then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('input.search').click(function(){
             $(this).attr("value", " ");
      });
});
```

You had a few typos in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use html5 placeholder

```
<input class="search" placeholder="Search" type="text" size="18" name="s" id="s">
```

And make correct your code with this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('input .search').click(function(){
             $(this).attr("value", "");
      });
});
</script>
```

You forget to `'` in search and  `$(".this")` to `$(this)`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Placeholder and also there is a typo in your code:-

`$(".this").attr("value", "");`  :- Incorrect

`$(this).attr("value", "");` :- correct

Answer (score 0):

I think you better use the HTML attribute `placeholder` like all the other answers suggest.

Here I'll explain what's wrong with your JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('input .search).click(function(){ // the string isn't closed and you have to use 'input.search', because 'input .search' looks for a child element of an input
             $(".this").attr("value", ""); // it's only this, not ".this"
      });
});
```

This code works

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('input.search').focus(function(){
             $(this).attr("value", "");
      }); 
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rkxmby1f/

Answer (score 0):

You have some typo mistake so it's not working:

```
 $('.search').click(function(){
        $(this).attr("value", "");
  });
```

**First:** `$('input .search)` you didn't close `'`.

**Second:** Use `$(this)` instead of `$(".this")`

Check Your updated [Fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/huat81z4/1/)

**Note:** I suggest to use `placeholder` instead of it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You want it to disappear immediate after your click,

Here it is using **JavaScript**

**JS** : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x0gyyemq/)

```
$(".search").click(function()
{
   $(".search").prop("value","");
});
```

**OR**

Placeholder attribute of HTML

**HTML**

```
<input class="search" placeholder="Search" type="text" size="18" name="s" id="s">
```

> Note: It will only disappear after you start typing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.search').on('focus', function() {
       $(this).val(""); 
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this too, it is simple ...

```
<input class="text-input" type="text" value="Search" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Search') this.value = '';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Search';"/>
```